# I am getting an error regarding the code only when I upload my files in to the server but the code is working good in my local host

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am working with asp.net in visual studio and I have a code that is working in my local cost but when the file is upploaded in to the server then I am getting an server error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.mytasks_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'linkButton2_Click' and no extension method 'linkButton2_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.mytasks_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 98:                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="TaskID" >
Line 99:                      <ItemTemplate>
Line 100:                         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" OnClick="linkButton2_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
Line 101:                     </ItemTemplate>
Line 102:                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the error I am getting , The code that I used is

in CS file: the method is used

```
 protected void linkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/View.aspx?TaskID=" + ((LinkButton)sender).Text);
        }
```

in the design page this is the code that is present:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="TaskID" >
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" OnClick="linkButton2_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload all of your updates in your local to your server specially the ASPX and the DLL of your Project and use relative path when locating file if it is working on you local it should work also in your server thanks

Comment: I uploaded all the updates and dll file with aspx but I am getting the same error , will it be problem with the version of softwares we use like the visual studio and I have .net 4.5 on my laptop but in the server it is .net 4.x(i) .

Comment: Yes it can be the problem